# Use semaphores in C to protect variable within for loop

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to use semaphores to avoid that a global variable is changed by threads and this variable is supposed to increment within the for loop. My main objective is to protect the variable cnt from the threads so it can increment within the for loop. However, I don't know how to do it because this is the first time I work with semaphores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


sem_t semaphore;
int cnt = 0; //global shared variable
void *threadProd(void *param); //threads call this function.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int niters;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2; //thread ids
    sem_init(&semaphore,0,1);
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <niters>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    niters = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadProd,  &niters);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadProd,  &niters);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL); //wait for thread to finish
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    //check answer:
    if(cnt != (2 * niters))
        printf("Incorrect answer, cnt = %d\n", cnt);
    else
        printf("Correct answer, cnt = %d\n", cnt);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
    exit(0);
}

//Thread routine
void *threadProd(void *vargp)
{
    sem_wait(&semaphore);
    int upper = *((int *) vargp);
    for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
        cnt ++;
    sem_post(&semaphore);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a semaphore is the best tool for enforcing mutual exclusion?  Would a mutex work better, or more simply?

Comment: What's your specific question? We can't answer "I'm kinda confused"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was asked to use semaphore that's why I'm trying to use it but I have read that mutex work fine as well

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry for that! Like I said, I'm trying to protect the variable cnt form the threads so it can increment within the for loop

Comment: You already wrote that, but it's not a question. What problem are you having using a semaphore to protect the variable?

Comment: The semaphore needs to be a global variable, or you need to pass a pointer to it to the thread function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler earlier I tried this: ```void *threadProd(void *vargp)
{
    sem_wait(&semaphore);
    int upper = *((int *) vargp);
    for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
        cnt ++;
    sem_post(&semaphore);
    return NULL;
}``` but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Yea, It is global!!

Comment: I will fix the code that I first posted

Comment: The code you say you tried doesn't show you checking the return values from `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()`.  Especially when things don't work, you should check those return values — it might be informing you there's a problem.  Your proposed locking scheme means that the two threads should be running in mutual exclusion; only one thread can acquire the semaphore at a time, and it does all its processing before releasing the semaphore for use by the other thread.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Then provide the code for an MCVE.  (Note the "Minimal" part of MCVE. Also note the "Complete" part.  The code shown doesn't include `<pthread.h>` which indicates 'incomplete' to me.)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!